# How to select css id's with numbers in them?

Tags: css

So I want to target multiple html element(s) like the below using a regular expression in a css selector:

```
<input id="something_stuff_013_work" />
<input id="something_stuff_016_work" />
```

The following CSS selector doesn't seem to work:

```
input[id*='[0-9]*_work']
```

I need to do something with digits in the regular expression because the inputs can be dynamically added and will be assigned ids with digits in them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are classes for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about using the following selector:

`input[id^='something_stuff_'][id$='_work']`

It will get inputs with id starting with "something_stuff_" and finishing with "_work".

Comment: I think the question says each individual number in the `ID`s must be targeted. The attribute substring selectors target a group.or range of values.

Comment: Perfect! That works with invalid ids like a GUID stating with a number too. For example: `#8ab58c40-60c9-4984-adb5-13c44160459a` Don't ask why we are using that as an id though...

Answer (score 4):

CSS does not support regexes in selectors. Use classes or starts-from and ends-with attribute selectors.

Comment: Regular expressions are just patterns used to match values in strings. CSS substring matching attribute selectors, I would respectfully argue, are regular expressions. I use regex in my .htaccess files, others use them in JavaScript, so why not CSS? Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

An approach to this problem would be to use classes instead of ids and have things that are styled the same to be classed the same. for example:

```
<input id="something_stuff_01_work" class="input_class">
<input id="something_stuff_02_work" class="input_class">
<input id="something_stuff_03_work" class="input_class">
```

Then select the class instead of the id.

```
.input_class {
    sweetstyleofawesomeness;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try prefixing the numeric id with \3.

I came across this today, it was the selector generated using chrometools, I'd not seen it before, and it works using Chromium Webdriver:

#\37

Full selector used is "#\37  > div > div.cell-text".

This was a selector to select an element with id = "7".

It (prefixing with \3) seems to work throughout the document I am looking at automating, with my current setup.

Comment: It's a cool solution, but is not working in strict mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal