# Target divs with odd/even numbers at the end of their IDs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have divs with IDs `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, etc.

I want to target all divs with and ID ending in an odd/even number separately (in CSS).

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<!-- Other html here -->
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

The HTML is subject to change regularly, therefore is possible want to avoid having to change the CSS every time.

The divs aren't sequential which is why I haven't used `nth-child(even/odd)`. I want to avoid adding any new attributes to the divs if possible.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575349/how-to-select-css-ids-with-numbers-in-them) to a similar question using expressions in the CSS.

I want to achieve something like this in CSS

```
'#div' + 'even'
```

Could I use data- attributes? 
e.g. `data-target="1"`, `data-target="2"` etc.

Comment: if the range is known (from 1 to 9 for example) you can easily create all the combination

Comment: @Turnip I can, but I want to be able to add more divs in future without having to mess with the CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The range of numbers is subject to change regularly and I want to avoid CSS alterations in future

Comment: but in all the cases an even number will always end with the same range of number so you can still define all the case easily

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see what you mean, I'll give that a try!

Comment: the answer is already given by Paulie by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires multiple selectors.

For instance to select odd numbered IDs, use a regular expressions symbol, `$`, to refer to the end of a string.

```
div[id$="1"],
div[id$="3"],
div[id$="5"],
div[id$="7"],
div[id$="9"] {}
```

```css
div[id$="1"],
div[id$="3"],
div[id$="5"],
div[id$="7"],
div[id$="9"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Odd</div>
<div id="div2">Even</div>
<div id="div3">Odd</div>
<div id="div4">Even</div>
<div id="div99999">Odd</div>
<div id="div2000">Even</div>
<div id="div333">Odd</div>
<div id="div377">Odd</div>
```